# e.graphics.drawstring showing text on printpreview but not printing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing

I am working with c# windows based application.[Visual Studio 2010]

In that i am trying to print the bill.

I have formed that bill using `e.Graphics.Drawstring`.

In this it is showing me printpreview with all the appropriate data.

But, when i take printout of that printpreview, its not showing me items in the bill.[Particular part of print preview. Other data is showing].

**My code is as follows:**

```
e.Graphics.DrawString("Amount", drawFont, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(tempX + 600, tempY, dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width, dataGridView1.Rows[1].Height), str);

    while (i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1)
            {

                if (height > e.MarginBounds.Height)
                {
                    height = 100;
                    width = 100;
                    e.HasMorePages = true;
                    return;
                }
                height += dataGridView1.Rows[i].Height;

                e.Graphics.DrawString((idInCol).ToString(), drawFont, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(tempX, ((i*22)+(tempY+25)), dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width, dataGridView1.Rows[0].Height), str);


                e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].FormattedValue.ToString().Trim(), drawFont, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(tempX + 30, ((i * 22) + (tempY +25)), 500, dataGridView1.Rows[0].Height), str);

                e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].FormattedValue.ToString(), drawFont, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(tempX + 400, ((i * 22) + (tempY +25)), dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width, dataGridView1.Rows[0].Height), drawFormat);
                width += dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width;

                              e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].FormattedValue.ToString().Trim(), drawFont, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(tempX + 500, ((i * 22) + (tempY +25)), dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width, dataGridView1.Rows[0].Height), drawFormat);
                width += dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width;

                               e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].FormattedValue.ToString().Trim(), drawFont, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(tempX + 600, ((i * 22) + (tempY +25)), dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width, dataGridView1.Rows[0].Height), drawFormat);
                width += dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width;
                idInCol++;
                i++;
            }
```

**Here is my screenshot of bill:**

[image]

In this its not showing me bill particulars when i take print out. Every other data is shown in the printout except that one.

I have pasted the code (while loop) from which i fetches that bill particulars(items,serial nums,etc).

Is there anything missing in my code?

or

Have I done anything wrong in the code?

Please help me.

Comment: What's conspicuously missing from the code is the BeginPrint event handler.  Required to get the "i" variable reset back to 0.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is two month old and that you probably found the bug or gave up.

Anyway here I go : Here I'm assuming the variable `i` is declared globaly to the class. If it's the case you need to reset `i` to 0 after the while loop is done.

To confirm that you need to reset `i` simply debug you app and check `i` value the second time you go into that method (the real printing one). Also if you directly print without preview it should work.

Comment: helped me. +1. I added a Begin Print Event and there initialized the variable to 0. This fixed the issue. I am starting the bounty for this answer.

Comment: @pkkg why you start a bounty, when you have your issue fixed. the purpose of bounty is to attract answers on unsolved questions.